# Can the host disable recording in Webex?

Tags: webex

In my company laptops, our webex has permanently the recording menu entry disabled. If someone external joins a meeting that is hosted by me in my company laptop, will he able to record in his device that is not a company device? Or webex will automatically disable his recording menu entry as well because I am the host and my company disabled them in our devices?

Comment: Even if it's disabled in WebEx client but he would still be free to use other means of recording.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't ask that

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out that it's easy to circumvent. So even if it is disabled you can't really stop someone. As for your question [this](https://communities.cisco.com/thread/50211?start=0&tstart=0) would suggest it's yours (as in the operator of that session) to decide. You could easily test it by creating a session and accessing it from a non company network device.